# Coin Flipping Game

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A friend asked me a question today.  Consider the following coin flipping game.  At round 1 of the game, we have a $100$ fair coins, and we flip them all.  If we get any heads, we set those aside, and begin round 2 with the remaining coins.  During round $i$ the player gets 2 tries.  If the player gets all tails 2 times in a row during any round, then he loses.  Also, the game ends if he ends up getting all the $100$ coins flipped to heads.  The question is, what is the expected number of coins that the player can get? I am hoping for a closed form solution.  I feel like this should have an easy solution, but I don't see it.

Comment: So, the game continues until either two throws give no further "heads" or all coins are "heads" ? And you want $E$(number of "heads") ? If so, I don't think that this is easy. A simulation could give an approximate value, but to calculate the exact value will be difficult.

Comment: @Peter Yes that is correct. I was able to use simulation to find an answer. It may be true a closed form is nearly impossible, but I was unsure if I was missing some combinatorial approach.

Comment: Please show the result of your simulation!

Answer (score 0):

If $\ E_r\ $ is the expected number of coins the player gets when he starts with $\ r\ $ coins, then $\ E
_0=0, E_1 =\frac{1}{4}\cdot 0 + \frac{3}{4}\cdot 1=\frac{3}{4} \ $, and you can calculate $\ E_1, E_2, \dots, E_{100}\ $ recursively from the formula
\begin{eqnarray}
E_r &=& \frac{1}{4^r}\cdot 0\ + \frac{2^r+1}{4^r}\sum_\limits{j=1}^r{r \choose j}\left(j+E_{r-j}\right)\\
&=&\left(1+\frac{1}{2^r}\right)\frac{r}{2} +\frac{2^r+1}{4^r}\sum_\limits{j=1}^r {r \choose j}E_{r-j}\ .
\end{eqnarray}
I doubt if there's a simple closed form expression for $\ E_r\ $.  For the first few I get 
$\ E_2= \frac{55}{32}\approx 1.72, E_3=\frac{5589}{2048}\approx 2.73, E_4=\frac{489,413}{2^{16}}\approx 3.73\ $, and $\ E_{100}\approx 99.7327\ $.

**Addendum:** In the above analysis I was assuming that the player got two tries in *every* round, *including the first*. It wasn't clear to me whether this was the case or not.  For the purposes of calculating $\ E_{100}\ $ from the above recursion it has to be assumed that all the games with *fewer* than $100$ coins are played this way.  But if this isn't the case for the actual game, the formula for $\ E_{100}\ $ in terms of $E_0, E_1, \dots, E_{99}\ $ would have to be modified as follows:
$$ E_{100}=50 + \frac{1}{2^{100}}\sum_\limits{j=1}^{100} {100 \choose j}E_{100-j}\ .$$
The difference in the numerical value of $\ E_{100}\ $ given by this formula and the previous one is so tiny that my $16$-decimal precision of my calculator wasn't sufficient to detect it.